# cliente e servidor UDP enviam dados mas não recebem(C windows)

Tags: c, socket

Olá estou tentando criar uma aplicação que realiza troca de dados na rede, pra isso existe uma conexão inicial usando sockets TCP que está funcionando normalmente, depois vem a utilização dos sockets UDP, no entanto não consigo realizar a troca de dados, a função sendto retorna sempre a quantidade de bytes adequada, para a leitura eu uso a função select pra determinar quando existem dados disponíveis para leitura, e nunca há, então os dados do servidor e do cliente nunca chegam ao destino. A criação dos sockets é feita da seguinte forma:

Criar o socket udp: `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)`

logo depois eu chamo a função bind, passando o soccket e uma estrutura sockaddr_in construída da seguinte forma:

```
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(port);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

::bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(sockaddr));
```

estou utilizando ::bind, porque o nome do método que realiza a operação também é bind e o VS estava dando conflito

depois da função bind eu apenas chamo os métodos recvfrom e sendto para ler e enviar os dados da seguinte forma:

```
read = recvfrom(sock_fd, data, length, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&o_addr, &l)
sent = sendto(sock_fd, data, length, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&o_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))
```

para determinar se existe algum dado para leitura eu chamo a função select da seguinte forma:

```
int r;
struct timeval tv = { 0, 0 };
fd_set fds;

FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(sock, &fds);

r = select(sock + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

if (FD_ISSET(sock, &fds))
    return true;
return false;
```

e nesse caso ela sempre retorna falso, o teste está sendo feito em duas máquinas diferentes. Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.